# If inside 'elif' ignored / not working with autosmooth script

Tags: python

Here is a script that checks is auto smooth is on and if yes just turns it off.

Ideally when you want to turn it on for the first time it should also set the shading angle value.

And then check if the default 180 is used and if not realize that a custom value is used and only turn on/ff autosmooth.

But the script ignores the if 180Dgeree check and thus never sets the initial angle to 30 degrees.

```
#Set AutoSmooth
class SetAutoSmooth(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "set.autosmooth"
    bl_label = "Set Auto Smooth"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    def execute(self, context):

        if bpy.context.object.data.use_auto_smooth == (True):
            bpy.context.object.data.use_auto_smooth = False           
        elif bpy.context.object.data.use_auto_smooth == (False):
             bpy.context.object.data.use_auto_smooth = True
             if bpy.context.object.data.auto_smooth_angle == (3.14159):
                bpy.context.object.data.auto_smooth_angle = 0.523599
             bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()

        return{'FINISHED'}
```

Comment: Maybe this should be migrated to Stackoverflow? The problem here is not bpy. (I obviously don't mind answering the question but it's usefulness will be limited without zooming-in to the to real cause of the problem..)

Comment: Do you mean this should go to stackoverflow because this is maybe a bug?

Comment: Yeah, the bug was in how you thought the comparison of two floats would work. Interesting problem but I think i've shown in my answer that the heart of the problem can be conveyed without the use of an operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is not that the *if* statement in the *elif* was ignored, but rather the statement itself didn't evaluate to `True`. To help debug your control flow consider adding a temporary *else* statement with a `print()`. Even if you then still don't understand why an *if* statement isn't `True` you'll have localized the problem, and you can try to solve the real issue: *comparing floats*.

As a test you can even run this directly from the TextEditor, and check the terminal / console for the print statements.

```
some_value = 0.343523435235
if some_value == 0.34352:
    # do something
    print('yep')
else:
    print('some_value ({0}) is not equals to 0.34352'.format(some_value))
```

Use some aliasing and the rounding as suggested by jerryno. Another readability improvement is the inclusion of `radians(180)` and `radians(30)`. These carry extra meaning to the reader (mostly you) than a rough float does.

```
import math   #  <--- yes!
from math import radians

class SetAutoSmooth(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "set.autosmooth"
    bl_label = "Set Auto Smooth"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    # have a poll check for active_object (optional)

    def execute(self, context):

        data = bpy.context.object.data
        data.use_auto_smooth ^= True  # inverts

        # use the boolean directly, else it's like saying: if True == True
        if data.use_auto_smooth:
            if round(data.auto_smooth_angle, 5) == round(radians(180), 5):
                data.auto_smooth_angle = radians(30)
            bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()

        return{'FINISHED'}
```

seen as the extra bit is only intended to be done if the use_auto_smooth is True after the inversion, then that will still need an if-statement. If you see so much repetition of code characters you need to think about using aliases (a variable to store a reference lookup) . It's easier to read and easier to write.

---

**some Python notes**

*math.isclose()*

Python 3.5 will be getting / has a new feature for testing if a float is close to another float, so we won't necessarily need to use rounding anymore. This feature is called 'approximate equality': read about it here https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0485/

`math.isclose(a, b, relative_tolerance, absolute_tolerance)`

*inverting a boolean*

These two lines are functionally equivalent

```
data.use_auto_smooth = not data.use_auto_smooth
data.use_auto_smooth ^= True
```

The `^=` is an [`augmented arithmetic assignment`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_assignment)

Comment: pretty great idea to to place localized print statements to check for issues. Why is a poll for active object needed here?

Comment: well, it might not be needed if your menu already had such a poll. else  there is no such thing as `obj.data.use_auto_smooth` and you'll get an exception.

Comment: it doesn't need to necessarily be active_object, I could imagine a scenario where you might want to do something similar for multiple selected_objects at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

If you print the default autosmooth angle, the result is `3.1415927410125732`. So, either compare against this number, or round the angle to the to the same as your comparing to.

This works:

```
if bpy.context.object.data.use_auto_smooth == (True):
    bpy.context.object.data.use_auto_smooth = False           
elif bpy.context.object.data.use_auto_smooth == (False):
    bpy.context.object.data.use_auto_smooth = True
    if bpy.context.object.data.auto_smooth_angle == (3.1415927410125732):
        bpy.context.object.data.auto_smooth_angle = 0.523599
    bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
```

or:

```
if bpy.context.object.data.use_auto_smooth == (True):
    bpy.context.object.data.use_auto_smooth = False           
elif bpy.context.object.data.use_auto_smooth == (False):
    bpy.context.object.data.use_auto_smooth = True
    if round(bpy.context.object.data.auto_smooth_angle, 5) == (3.14159):
        bpy.context.object.data.auto_smooth_angle = 0.523599
    bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
```

Comment: never compare float numbers like this, always round them..

Comment: That works - oddly my script initially worked and I moved on and then later it  did not work which is why I posted it. The rounding step does it.

Answer (score 0):

To add the poll function this will work

```
@classmethod
def poll(cls, context):
    return context.active_object is not None

def execute(self, context):

    for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        if obj.data.use_auto_smooth == (True):
            obj.data.use_auto_smooth = False
            print('AutoSmooth Off')
        elif obj.data.use_auto_smooth == (False):
            obj.data.use_auto_smooth = True
            print('AutoSmooth On')
            if round(obj.data.auto_smooth_angle, 5) == (3.14159):
                obj.data.auto_smooth_angle = 0.523599
                print('numbers check')
            bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
            print('Shade Smooth')
    return{'FINISHED'}
```